# When to use @Import in a Micronaut application that imports @Singleton from external libraries

Tags: micronaut

I've read what the Micronaut docs have to say about when to use @Import and it makes perfect sense, but working with the framework in migrating some previously spring boot apps doesn't seem to line up.

Here are some things I've seen:

- external @Singleton injected into a Micronaut application @Singleton works without @Import
- multiple @Import usages included in a Micronaut application via enabling annotations from multiple external libraries do not all get applied
- the order in which enabling annotations from multiple external libraries are applied in the Micronaut application dramatically changes the occurrence of "NonUniqueBeanException
  ".

Any advise about when to use @Import and when not to use it would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.